# react route links cannot match js file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I followed a tutorial in w3school for routing, but the import part doesn't work and it returns an error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iExy.png). This is the folder structure [app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PZ8u.png) and index file code below.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Pages } from 'react';
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Blogs from "./pages/Blogs";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import NoPage from "./pages/NoPage";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
          <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is not with the react but you forgot to add extensions in the webpack config.
**Refer :** https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions

**Eg. :**

```
resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    }
```

Comment: could u give more detail maybe detail instruction

Comment: @linhcheee If you don't use WebPack then add .js extension while importing. eg `import Layout from "./pages/Layout.js";`

Comment: @linhcheee Whenever someone answers your question and if that solves your problem then accept the answer as solution. Refer : [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
```

Instead of writing like that, try this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

Btw, what's layout for? I think it's that making the error